# Querying postgresql using psql command in bash throws ERROR: relation "testschema.testtable" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, psql

On running the below command in bash throws:

> ERROR: relation "testschema.testtable" does not exist.

Command line:

```
psql -h "localhost" -d "postgres" -U "postgres" -c "select * from TestSchema.TestTable;"
```

Why is it searching relation rather than schema?
How can I set default schema to be searched, and can I set a list of multiple schemas from multiple databases as default list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *Why is it searching relation rather than schema?*

`TestSchema.TestTable` **is** a relation (table). I is a fully qualified table name.

The reason it's not finding it, is most probably because you created the schema and the table using doublequotes:

```
create table "TestSchema"."TestTable" (...)
```

which makes the names case sensitive and forces you to always use quotes to qualify the name. Please see the manual for details about "delimited identifiers" (aka "quoted identifiers):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

> *How can I set default schema to be searched*

See the "set schema" statement: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set.html

You can also define a default schema using the `ALTER USER` command.

> *can I set a list of multiple schemas from multiple databases as default list*

Yes, set the search_path configuration variable: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-SEARCH-PATH

This can also be set permanently through an `ALTER USER` statement.